# Why is not displayed scrolling to my list?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this sample:

[link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vKgKBy)

**CODE HTML:**

```
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 no-padding space-col-app text-left" id="appoi_time">
       <label>Time:</label>
       <input type="text" name="time" id="time" readonly="" onclick="$('#select_time').show();">

       <div id="select_time" >
            <ul>
              <li onclick="jQuery('#time').val('06:00')">06:00</li>
              <li onclick="jQuery('#time').val('06:15')">06:15 </li>
              <li onclick="jQuery('#time').val('06:30')">06:00</li>
              <li onclick="jQuery('#time').val('06:45')">06:15 </li>
              <li onclick="jQuery('#time').val('07:00')">06:00</li>
              <li onclick="jQuery('#time').val('07:15')">06:15 </li>                                                
              <li onclick="jQuery('#time').val('07:30')">06:00</li>
              <li onclick="jQuery('#time').val('07:45')">06:15 </li> 
               <li onclick="jQuery('#time').val('08:00')">06:00</li>
              <li onclick="jQuery('#time').val('08:15')">06:15 </li>
              <li onclick="jQuery('#time').val('08:30')">06:00</li>
              <li onclick="jQuery('#time').val('08:45')">06:15 </li>
              <li onclick="jQuery('#time').val('09:00')">06:00</li>
              <li onclick="jQuery('#time').val('09:15')">06:15 </li>                                                
              <li onclick="jQuery('#time').val('09:30')">06:00</li>
              <li onclick="jQuery('#time').val('09:45')">06:15 </li>                                                          
          </ul>
 </div>
```

What I want to do is to put the scroll bar's always the element `select_time`

At this time scrolling does not appear unless you down ... I want to always be displayed.

I put a picture more clearly understand what I mean.

How can I get the scroll to be displayed always? You can help me solve this problem please?

Thank you in advance!

[image]

Comment: Which browser are your using? Its working fine with chrome 51.0.2704.103

Comment: It is working fine for me? [image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/2F4DL.png)

Comment: all with chrome work and I have the latest version.

Comment: Working fine... what's the problem.?

Answer (score 0):

in your css make height: auto, and remove overflow-y so css becomes as below

```
#select_time{
height:auto;
border:1px solid #ccc;
display:none;
position:absolute;
background:white;
top:63px;
width:100%;
z-index:99999;
}
```

Comment: If I put the height:auto I don't have scroll bar

Comment: then add overflow-y: visible